# Graphic Design SE - Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

For our thanks to the users that helped make this site the *resounding* success that its become, if you appear on the first two pages [of this list](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), I'll be reaching out to you within the next 7 - 10 days to get your shipping and size information.

Why would I want such information, you ask? Well that's a very good question! I want to send you some of this *very* awesome stuff that we've put together for Graphic Design SE!

We've got stickers!

[image: They stick]

We've got shirts!

[image: They wear!]

We've got notebook covers!

[image: They cover!]

Note that a notebook is included, but is just a *little* smaller than a standard Moleskine, so it'll be a little loose as the cover is designed to fit a Moleskine exactly. The Moleskine model the sleeve was design for is 5" x 8.25," 240 sheets. You should be able to find it in your local bookstore or online. We tried hard to just get them included, but couldn't source them.

If your name isn't on the first two pages, don't worry! There will be plenty left over for us to give out to folks attending events where they can promote the site, and the occasional contest that we'll hold.

Thanks again for being awesome, and I'll be in touch with you soon!

Comment: hey. Cool. Thanks!

Comment: Also. Wow. I post too much here. (Can you tell I have a boring day job?) :)

Comment: Yay!! Presents!!

Comment: Also worth noting that our design team had these ready weeks ago, sorry for the delay on my end in getting this posted :) Jin & Co. Really put some love into this.

Comment: Wow! That's beyond cool!

Comment: Whoa! Super cool!

Comment: Sweet! Thank you very much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you contacting?

Comment: Yay! pressies! I second @Ryan - particular kudos to the new-new people who made the top two pages. Particularly nice, as the moleskine cover was my idea :)

Comment: ...and now we can have "your moleskine doodle of the week" :D

Comment: I'm excited! I can personally attest that the StackExchange swag is *very* nice. The shirts in particular are great.

Comment: This is really cool!

Comment: Well, I am wayyy down on the 48 page, No hopes of getting this stuff...

Comment: Should we have been contacted by now?

Comment: Finally a promo tshirt I would actually wear! :-)

Comment: Loves me my Moleskine. The cover will be great to keep it warm in the cold weather... :)

Comment: Want to represent with this swaggary so bad!!

Comment: Has anyone been contacted yet? How do they contact? I'm not even sure if I have an email linked to StackExchange.

Comment: @Ryan I have yet to receive an email. WE'VE BEEN DUPED!

Comment: @DA01 me neither, so I guess there's something up in general.

Comment: Email was received today, thanks!

Comment: I just got my email...didn't ever expect be be in on something like this!

Comment: Got my email! I submitted my info via the form! Thanks again!!

Comment: Thank you @jin and the complete team...waiting filled all the details!!! excited!!

Comment: I am at page [41](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?page=41&tab=reputation&filter=all) lol :D

Comment: I've also filled out the details,  ahhhh I can't wait :D

Comment: Merch came in today, thanks! :-)

Comment: Arrived today! It really arrived :D

Comment: :( Still waiting on mine

Comment: Years later, a few requests to Abby, and still waiting. :'( @TimPost

Answer (score 14):

errrr.... Let's see... how can I possibly write enough to meet the minimum character requirements and say..... **too cool and thanks!** :)

Update 08.27.14 -- Got mine today as well. Nice stuff. Thanks again!

Answer (score 10):

Awesome thanks! And congrats to all the active members that get it especially some of our newer active members that just made the cutoff: Vnovak, SaturnsEye, and joojaa!

Answer (score 7):

Well, lawdie lawdie and fer gosh sakes! A gracious "thank you" to all involved. It's been an interesting, sometimes roller-coastery ride over the past couple of years, and it was a win for all of us when the site graduated from beta at long last!

[Update: The package arrived Friday 29th. Great stuff, and thank you! :)]

Answer (score 6):

Woot!! Just got my package, Thank you!!!

[image]

Comment: Class act! Now you just have to wait for people to stop you in the street bowing to your superior SE-cred :)

Comment: Looking good there!

Comment: @ckpepper02 GD's iron man..

Answer (score 4):

Wow! That is great. Thank you very much.

EDIT: Got mine yesterday. **Thank you!**

Question, **I got two distinct packages** for some reason. Two shirts, two sets of decals, two covered notebooks. Did I get someone else's package as well? Would you like me to return one or send it along to the rightful recipient?

Answer (score 3):

This is GREAT! I can't wait till I get my set in the mail! **Thanks A Whole Lot Guys!**

Answer (score 2):

Got my package today! Thanks to the Stack Exchange people!

Comment: aaaahh.. then we will see how long it takes to reach us out on the fringes of the world..

Comment: Got mine today! yaaay!

Answer (score 1):

Whoa received my package today, though I was not sure that you guys will deliver it in India (I am staying some where in sands :D),  its truly awesome!!! Thank a ton GDSE!!! \m/

Answer (score 0):

Well damn... joined too late :P

Good initiative though. Love the SX community!

Answer (score -1):

Doh!  [First name on page 3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?page=3&tab=reputation&filter=all).  I tearfully watch my stickers slip from my grasp...